# Evolution-EWS and MS Exchange

Tags: email, thunderbird, evolution

I was using ExQuilla and Thunderbird to get my MS Exchange email and calendar. My trial is expiring and I was hoping to not have to pay. I am attempting to re-create this in Evolution-EWS, however I am getting the error `The reported error was “456 ”.`

My email is michaelminer@company.com, when connecting with thunderbird and ExQuilla I used my email and the host url `https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx`. In thunderbird clicking test URL opened the MS Exchange login and 2 factor page which then asked to send me a text message. Fetch URL in Evolution-EWS only gives me the error.

Is there a way I can get past this step?

Edit: My authentication type is set to Basic.

Edit 2: If I attempt to set the Authentication type to OAuth2, I get the error that my email does not support OAuth2.

Edit 3: When I click `Fetch URL` the OAB URL is never filled in.